What is the point of origin of a Spectator-reflected spell?
In the same, as-yet-unfinished, battle that prompted this question, the warlock has been shooting eldritch blasts at a Spectator.
The Spectator has:

Spell Reflection. If the spectator makes a successful saving throw against a spell, or a spell attack misses it, the spectator can choose another creature (including the spellcaster) it can see within 30 feet of it. The spell targets the chosen creature instead of the spectator. If the spell forced a saving throw, the chosen creature makes its own save. If the spell was an attack, the attack roll is rerolled against the chosen creature.

When the warlock misses its attack roll on the Spectator, the Spectator can choose another creature, including the warlock, and force the warlock to make a ranged spell attack roll against them.  But from where does this attack originate - from the square of the spectator, or the square of the warlock?
If the attack originates from the square of the warlock, can the spectator target a creature that is within 30 feet of it, but at greater than 120 feet from the warlock, or behind Total Cover from the vantage point of the warlock?  That is, is the "it can see within 30 feet" to be read as an additional targeting condition to the spell, or is it, specific-over-general, replacing the targeting rules of the spell (which include Range and Line of Sight)?
If the attack originates from the square of the Spectator, and there is a foe next to the warlock, does the warlock still have disadvantage on the attack roll?
Suppose the warlock, concerned about accidentally targeting allies, switched to a spell with a more limited range than the Spectator's 30 feet (this particular warlock has vampiric touch, which permits you to make "a melee spell attack against a creature within your reach.")
When the warlock misses its attack roll on the Spectator, the Spectator can choose another creature, including the warlock, and force the warlock to make a melee spell attack roll against them.  But from where does this attack originate - from the square of the spectator, or the square of the warlock?
If the attack originates from the square of the warlock, can the spectator target a creature that is within 30 feet of it, but outside the reach of the warlock?  If the attack originates from the square of the Spectator, can the Spectator target a creature that is within 30 feet of it, but outside its own reach?  That is, is the "it can see within 30 feet" to be read as an additional targeting condition to the spell, or is it, specific-over-general, replacing the targeting rules of the spell (which include Range)?
Related, but about spells with saves rather than attack rolls:
Does a Morkoth's Spell Reflection work against area-of-effect spells like Fireball?
Spectator Spell Reflection for Hail of Thorns?

The point of origin of the reflected spell is the Spectator.
The Reaction text says (emphasis mine):

Spell Reflection. If the spectator makes a successful saving throw against a spell, or a spell attack misses it, the spectator can choose another creature (including the spellcaster) it can see within 30 feet of it. The spell targets the chosen creature instead of the spectator.

The text clearly says that the new target is a creature within 30 feet of it, and "it" is the Spectator itself.
Therefore, since

The spell targets the chosen creature instead of the spectator

this means that it could extend the initial range of the spell, and moreover creatures that could not be targeted by the caster can be now affected by the spell (for example, a creature beyond a corner with Total Cover from the original caster but not from the Spectator).
The description specifies that

[...] If the spell was an attack, the attack roll is rerolled against the chosen creature.

Therefore, in the situation depicted in the question (the warlock's Eldritch Blasts are redirected and there is a foe next to them) the attack role must be done with disadvantage per the quoted rule.
If the reflected spell targets the warlock, the attack roll must be done against warlock's AC.

I think that the name of the Reaction helps in providing guidance in what is happening: Spell Reflection strongly suggests that the spell is reflected, meaning that it reaches the proximity of the spectator and then it "bounces" towards other creature(s).

Yes, I do think the name of the ability is useful information, but it is sometimes hard to see how it would work.  The fight is now concluded, but during it the spectator was missed with a spiritual weapon attack.  If a spell's range can be extended, how is a melee attack 'reflected' 30 feet away?  I also think you misunderstand or misstate the 'foe in your face' rule.  The warlock has disadvantage not because they are targeting a foe next to them, but because there is a foe next to them, regardless of who they target.  If you can resolve these I will upvote.

@Kirt Yes, I agree that in the middle of a combat the DM should take a decision and make a ruling in order to do not make the table wait too long, and sometimes it is not really easy. For the melee spell attack, I agree that is counterintuitive, but this is magic: it works so because... magic. I would explain it as the magical energy coming from the weapon is reflected/bounced 30 feet away. Yes, thank for spotting the error, I corrected it!

I appreciate the revision -  Upvoted

This came up in a game recently. First, here's the feature.

Spell Reflection. If the spectator makes a successful saving throw against a spell, or a spell attack misses it, the spectator can choose another creature (including the spellcaster) it can see within 30 feet of it. The spell targets the chosen creature instead of the spectator. If the spell forced a saving throw, the chosen creature makes its own save. If the spell was an attack, the attack roll is rerolled against the chosen creature.

You ask

But from where does this attack originate - from the square of the spectator, or the square of the warlock?


If the attack originates from the square of the warlock, can the spectator target a creature that is within 30 feet of it, but at greater than 120 feet from the warlock, or behind Total Cover from the vantage point of the warlock?

The range of the original spell is irrelevant, now overridden by the feature. The spell now has a range of 30' from the spectator that it can see. Sure, the spell itself originated from the caster, but the feature, Spell Reflection, originates from the spectator.
The rather terse

If the spell was an attack, the attack roll is rerolled against the chosen creature.

is a bit more of a conundrum. Do I care about the original caster's perspective, or that of the spectator? Since it says "the attack roll," I'm assuming we still use the modifiers from the spellcaster. I'm not a fan of how this is presented, as it adds some confusion. However, the feature clearly restates the requirements as from the perspective of the spectator (visibility and range), so I don't think it makes sense to impart benefits or detriments from the vision or position of the original caster on the (new) target.
How I ruled
I didn't ask for a reroll and just used the original attack roll, only against the reflected target, which had to be within 30' and visible to the spectator. It just didn't make sense to me to ask for a reroll, as it would just slow the game down unnecessarily.

I would love to understand the downvotes. It's recommended in meta (though perhaps ignored) that downvotes be accompanied by a comment with a reason. I cannot improve a downvoted answer if I don't' understand the reason for the downvote.
